# MySQL row echos okay, except when returned as text input's value

Tags: php, mysql, input, escaping, apostrophe

So I have a small issue with apostrophes in MySQL when returning the rows into text boxes so they they may be edited.

The issue is that rows that include an apostrophe ( ' ) in the string of a column will `echo` fine as text on a page, but when echoed as the value of a text box, the string is cut at the apostrophe and ended with a slash.

I have removed the slash using `stripslashes($nam)` with `$nam` being the variable I load my Name column into using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. But the rest of the string is not being returned still.

Again, when echoed onto the page that lists all the rows, there are no issues, the full string is outputted as it should be, with apostrophes and no added slashes.

This is when the string is echoed onto the page:
[image: This is when the string is echoed onto the page]

This is when the string is echoed as the value of the text box:
[image: This is when the string is echoed as the value of the text box]

In Chrome's developer tools I can see the issue is the apostrophe is closing off the `value` tag too early and the rest of the string is being treated like an HTML property.
[image: Chrome developer tools]

So how do I stop this from happening, currently my code (a vastly cut down version to avoid filling the page with pointless unrelated code) that I use to echo is:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $nam = $row["Name"];
    $nam = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $nam);
    $nam = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $nam);
    echo "<label for='Name'>Name</label></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' placeholder='Item Name' value='".$nam."' required></td>";
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I started typing this question and thought "I better try this before I post because otherwise it could look really bad if it is such as simple fix."

**It turned out I was right.** I will post this question still, however, so that people who are starting out may learn from it as it is something so basic, and partly because I had already typed the question out.

**The Answer:**

Previously I was using quotation marks `"` to encapsulate what I wanted to echo, and apostrophes `'` to set values, so in this case, my code was:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' placeholder='Item Name' value='".$nam."' required>";
```

The key point to note is the code: `value='".$nam."'`.

Because the row was returning an apostrophe, I assume PHP was recognizing this apostrophe as the end of the `value` property and cutting my string short, hence the weird Chrome Developer Tools source code that included the rest of my string, sans apostrophe.

To fix this, I simply changed the apostrophes for quotation marks, and escaped them using a backslash `\`. To anyone who doesn't know, escaping is done by putting the backslash before the character you need to escape, and this removes any special abilities of this character. Had I have not escaped the quotation mark, then the quotation mark would have ended my `echo` and left me with a syntax error. By escaping it, I am telling PHP that the quotation mark is part of the HTML I want to `echo` and not the end of the `echo`.

So my new code is now:

```
echo "<input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' placeholder='Item Name' value=\"".$nam."\" required>";
```

So the lesson I learned is: Don't try to avoid escaping quotation marks by just using them to encapsulate your `echo`.